# When using subdomain on mailgun how to receive emails sent to rootdomain?

Tags: email, mailgun

When registering a domain on mailgun there is this text above the input:

> We recommend using a subdomain with Mailgun, like “mg.mydomain.com”. Using a subdomain you will still be able to send emails from your root domain e.g. “you@mydomain.com”.

I have registered mail.mydomain.com

I can catch all mails comming to *@mail.mydomain.com nicely through the routes. Now I want to catch all mails sent to *@mydomain.com

I interpreted the quoted text as if that was possible, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is simple: you can't

Answer (score 0):

You could obviously point mydomain.com to mailgun too, however, keep in mind that Mailgun does not provide POP3/IMAP mailboxes (https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/faq-mailbox-eol.html#discontinuing-pop3-imap-mailboxes).

Assuming you need mailboxes, there are different scenarios, and it depends on your use case I guess:

- You could point mydomain.com to another hoster, and for the relevant emails for mailgun set up a forwarder to mail.mydomain.com at mailgun.
- You can point mydomain.com to mailgun, and for emails where you need to store data, set up routes respectively (https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-receiving.html#how-to-start-receiving-inbound-email)